# Visual basic textbox not refreshing

Tags: loops, textbox, addition

I'm writing a code in visual basic to compute primes. The program runs in a loop, and i'm adding the new primes to a textbox, but it remains blank until the loop finishes. How can i add text to the textbox while in loop?

Comment: Is the form unresponsive, while the computation runs?

Comment: Yes, it is... Is that a problem?

Answer (score 0):

You are caclulating the primes on the UI thread, essentially freezing the UI while the loop runs. This is very bad for user experience: the textbox not updating is only one symptom.

Split off a worker thread for your caculation and invoke the UI thread just for UI updates.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an InputBox instead of a TextBox. The difference between a InputBox and a TextBox is that the InputBox pauses the loop allowing you to enter values while running. Here is an example of how to use an InputBox.

Dim Message As String
Dim Title As String
Dim MyValue As String

Message = "Enter a value between 1 and 3" ' Set prompt.
Title = "Input Box Demo" ' Set title.

' Display message, title.
MyValue = InputBox(Message, Title)
' Display dialog box at position 100, 100.
MyValue = InputBox (Message, Title,, 100, 100)

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6z0ak68w(v=vs.90).aspx